# how and why do "cpgz" files appear out of regular zip files?

Tags: macos, mac, checksum

for some reason under Mac OSX HIGH SIERRA I have noticed that once functioning .zip files are turning up with "cpgz" at the end of the file.(funny_movie.zip.cpgz) I have a feeling it has something to do with the file checksum but I have no Idea what to do to fix it? I have to find a solution to this or wind up losing some valuable (to me) files.

Comment: Did you try third party unzip tools like e.g. [The Unarchiver](https://theunarchiver.com/)?

Comment: Or use the commandline "unzip".

Comment: http://osxdaily.com/2013/02/13/open-zip-cpgz-file/ provides some assistance, but for MacOS issues, your best path to a solution may be found at https://apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

MacOS method of unzipping a zip file is to first create a new file with the zip.cpgz
extension before actually returning the contents of the ZIP archive.
It then opens this CPGZ archive and re-creates the ZIP file again, then
decompress it gives back into zip.cpgz file... and this goes on infinitely.

This may happen when macOS doesn't understand the type of ZIP compression used with
the file, so it thinks that you want to compress the file instead of decompressing it.
Since CPGZ is the default format used for compression, which is
Compressed UNIX CPIO Archive file,
the file is just being compressed and decompressed over and over again.

The solution is to use a third party tool such as PeaZip, 7-Zip, or
[The Unarchiver](https://theunarchiver.com/).

For more information, see:

- [How to Open a Zip File That Turns Into a CPGZ](http://osxdaily.com/2013/02/13/open-zip-cpgz-file/)
- [Open, Edit, & Convert CPGZ Files](https://www.lifewire.com/cpgz-file-2620362)